# Is it possible to use a loop for this type of query set?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
sc = new MySqlCommand("Update tbName set AvgTime=" + avgTimeArray[1]+ " where   PatternId=1", msc);
                sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

sc = new MySqlCommand("Update tbName set AvgTime=" + avgTimeArray[2]+ " where   PatternId=2", msc);
                sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

sc = new MySqlCommand("Update tbName set AvgTime=" + avgTimeArray[3]+ " where   PatternId=3", msc);
                sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is it possible to use a loop for this type of query set? If it is possble how to do it? (**avgtImeArray** is a array)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just use a loop. Do you have a specific question regarding what you've tried?

Comment: 1. Use loop. 2. Use `using`. 3. Use parameterized queries

Comment: @TimSchmelter My problem is how to write this part (avgTimeArray[1]).... I can't just put i (variable for loop) instead of 1,2,3....

Comment: @Sasa1234: why can't you do that?

Comment: @TimSchmelter because program takes it as i, not as a variable.

Comment: @Sasa1234: only if it's a string, but in your code you also access the array at given indices, f.e. `avgTimeArray[1]` which accesses the second item. So why can't you replace `1` with `i`?

Comment: Glad that no one has upvoted either of the current answers posted.  Both have SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < avgTimeArray.length; i++){
sc = new     MySqlCommand("Update tbName set AvgTime = @AvgTime where PatternId = @PatternID", msc);
sc.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("AvgTime", avgTimeArray[i].ToString())); 
sc.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("PatternID", i.ToString())); 
sc.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

This will work around your potential SQL injection vulnerability.  Note, code is untested. Answer based on Tinman7757's posted answer and tweaked as needed...

MSDN article on Parameterizing queries: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Bb738521(v=VS.100).aspx.  The problem with not parameterizing is it leaves the code open for someone with malicious intents to execute arbitrary SQL code (including but not limited to deletions and full blown table drops).  You will want to obviously prevent this wherever possible.

Comment: Why patternID is larger than array index?

Comment: Arrays start with an index of 0 and go up from there.  The original post shows pattern ID's starting at 1, so I made a presumption that pattern ID's will always start at 1, not zero.

Comment: But the array index also starts from 1 in the original post.

Comment: Okay, code tweaked accordingly.  To the Original poster, might be worth noting that this will actually skip over the first item in the array, if this is your intent, this code will work as is, if not, change the loop definition to i=0 and change PatternID to i+1.ToString when assigning to a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try something like:

```
  dim x as integer = 1
  Do
     dim MyAVG as Integer = avgTimeArray[x]
     sc = new MySqlCommand("Update tbName set AvgTime=" + MyAvg + " where PatternId=" + x, msc);
     sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
     x += 1
     if x > 3: exit do
  Loop
```

Comment: You have missed this part "avgTimeArray[3]" That is the problem I have faced.

Comment: @Sasa1234 So change the `3` to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < avgTimeArray.length; i++){
sc = new     MySqlCommand("Update tbName set AvgTime=" +  
avgTimeArray[i]+ " where   PatternId=" + i, msc);
sc.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

Like Tim Schmelter said use a loop. 'i' represents the index of the array  comparable to `arrayAtIndex[0],arrayAtIndex[1].`instead put it in a loop with a using statment wrapped around it. and use `arrayAtIndex[i]`

If you need to start from a higher index use `int i = 1`

Hope this has some value.